# Can't load image with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Am trying to load an image with SFML using Xcode, but everytime I run the program, the window  (which has been created using  the  code) flashes  and disappears...

Here's the code I am using:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1024
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 1024

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), "Orsome Game");



    while(window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event e;


        while(window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            switch (e.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();

                    break;
            }
        }

        sf::Image image;

        if(!image.loadFromFile("sprite.png")){
            return -1;
        }


        window.clear(sf::Color(255,255,255));

        window.display();

    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Have also put the image file where the c++ file is, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Which version of SFML?

Comment: Configure the working directory in your IDE to be the directory containing the image file.

Comment: Or try `if(!image.loadFromFile("C:/path/to/image/file/sprite.png")){` 9 times out of 10 this is because the program is looking for the file somewhere different from what the poster expected.

Comment: @John - tried this, the window remains now but no image

Comment: @Transformer Well I'm no expert on SFML but you don't seem to be doing anything to display the image, you just load it.

Comment: It would be a good idea to take the image loading outside of the window loop (put it before it). If you need to display it, load it into a texture and draw that using a sprite.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an `sf::Style::Default` in the RenderWindow arguments, straight after "Orsome Game" window name. Because you are using the pollEvent, that would allow you to exit the window by pressing the x button in the top right corner, like a default application layout.

**Is the picture in the same directory as your solution file? Or your main.cpp?**
It should be, of course. 
And, maybe, try loading your image with `Texture` and `Sprite`, like this:

```
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("picturename.png");
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(texture);
```

inside the while window is open loop.

To draw it:

```
// after window.clear() ...

//... your code

window.draw(sprite);

//... other things to draw

// and then, your window.display();
```

But, probably, your sf::Image should also work. Tell me how it goes

---

EDIT:

---

**Try this code and see if the window opens.** 
Otherwise, that might be the problem of setting up the SFML on your computer and you will have to find some good tutorial on how to set it up properly! But let's see:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 640), "Test", Style::Default);

    while (window.isOpen()) {

        Event _event;
        while (window.pollEvent(_event)) {
            switch (_event.type) {
            case Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }




        window.clear();


        // draw

        // ...

        window.display();

        }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should've but didn't work...the image file is in the  same directory as  the xcode file.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your declaration of screen sizes. Re-write them with int screenwidth = 1024;  and int screenheight = 1024. And try returning with 0, instead of EXIT_SUCCESS. And, perhaps, that would work

Comment: Starts flashing again with this in output: Failed to load image "/Users/myname/Desktop/SFML/sprite.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Program ended with exit code: 255

Comment: Have you loaded all .dll files of SMFL to your working directory?

Comment: Your installation folder with SFML must contain the .dll files that you would have to copy to your working directory of your project. 
I am not sure how the installation is done on MacOS, but I can definitely say that something is not installed either correctly, or completely. 
You can try and see, if the window draws, without your image. I have updated my answer, so you can check the code that must work. If not - look for tutorials on how to set it up properly.